# Reading excel into java - how to simplify

Tags: java, excel, spring, spring-mvc

I wrote code which I find a bit complicated and as a beginner searching for simpler solution. I have an excel table with 6 columns and 170 rows. My idea was to read cell by cell and store all cells into one List.

```
List<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();                       
        sh.forEach(row -> {                                             
                row.forEach(cell -> {                                       
                String cellvalue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);     
                lista.add(cellvalue);
                System.out.println(cellvalue);
            }); });
        workbook.close();
```

After that, iterating through this list and and storing cells into 6 list by number one to six. How I did it:

```
 ArrayList<String> lista1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> lista2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> lista3 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> lista4 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> lista5 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> lista6 = new ArrayList<String>();

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        ArrayList<String>[] liste = new ArrayList[]{lista1, lista2, lista3, lista4, lista5, lista6};

        for (int i = 6 ; i < lista.size(); i ++ ){                                                                  // i = 6  --->  preskoči prvi red
              liste[i % 6].add(lista.get(i)); }     //liste[i % 6] = liste[1] = liste[2] = liste[3] = liste[4], etc
        jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("INSERT INTO INS_RAZNO.ZAPOSLENICI_TEST VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
            @Override                                   
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                ps.setString(1, lista1.get(i));
                ps.setString(2, lista2.get(i));         
                ps.setString(3, lista3.get(i));     
                ps.setString(4, lista4.get(i));         //ćelije koje sadržavaju brojeve mogu se prenositi kao stringovi u NUMBER polje
                ps.setString(5, lista5.get(i));         //ćelije koje sadržavaju slova ne mogu se prenositi u NUMBER polje
                ps.setString(6, lista6.get(i));    
            }
```

I have used

```
 liste[i % 6].add(lista.get(i));
```

So, iterating through main list, i have 'i % 6' and by this value storing liste[i] in each list.

What I am thinking of is how to make this solution more simple. And by that maybe add some getter and setter method, but for me its hard to figure what should I connect with get and set. This is only my thought. 
If you have any other idea, please share with me. Thank you.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you have 6 lists rather than a list of lists.

Comment: Because I am beginner and have a limited knowledge. I asked this question in this purpose to find out how to simplify. That was an idea. :)
Edit: List are used to sort my data into columns. At first step I read cell by cell from left to right and then I store those values into lists. Each for one column, becouse of order.

Comment: Create a `class Row` that has a number of `column`. Create a `class Table` that has a number of `Row`. Populate the `table` from your Excel table. Read each `row` in the table into the database. You are using an OO language - write some objects! Perhaps create an `ExcelTableAdapter` to [adapt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) the Excel data to your Table API. Maybe create a `TableDataBatchPreparedStatementSetter` to use your `table` as data. Then you don't even have to read the whole lot into memory...

Comment: Is it too much to ask you to show me how?

Comment: You'll learn more from doing. Start by doing some data modelling. And if you ever find yourself writing procedural code similar to the above, throw it away and start by doing some data modelling.

Comment: OK. When I create class which has data of one row, how can I get values from table by one row?

Comment: ExcelDataModel ex = new ExcelDataModel();
ps.setString(1, ex.getIme());
What should I set as an argument into getIme() to get name value from tabel each time for one row?

Comment: Why are you collecting data into lists instead of doing the batch update in the first stream?

Comment: Because I am beginner and have a limited knowledge. I asked this question in this purpose to find out how to simplify. That was an idea. :) Edit: List are used to sort my data into columns. At first step I read cell by cell from left to right and then I store those values into lists. Each for one column, becouse of order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `List` of `String`, create a Java model class containing properties corresponding to each column. Then iterating through each row of the excel, create an instance representing that row and add it to the `List` of your model objects.

*To break it down-*

- Each row represents an Object, that is your model class.
- Columns of each row are the properties of that model class.

Comment: What are "Cmd" objects? This answer seems to miss the two dimensional nature of a table. "_Java Cmd class containing properties corresponding to each column_" & "_create an Object representing that row and add it to the List of Cmd objects_" - how can this "Cmd" object represent both a row & a column?

Comment: By cmd object I meant a Model object representing each Row of the excel.

Comment: The properties of the model class represent the columns and each instance of the model represent a single row.

Comment: Why would an "object representing each Row of the excel_" be called "Cmd". And why does "_a Java Cmd class contai[n] properties corresponding to each column_" in that case?

Comment: You can call it anything you want and that is how data is usually modeled, where each java property corresponds to a column. Is my answer really that hard to understand?

Comment: "Is my answer really that hard to understand?" => Yes, it is! That's the reason why @BoristheSpider asks you all those questions. He tries to push you in a direction to improve your answer by editing it and clearly answer those questions.

Comment: I have edited the answer, please check. If it still seems not understandable, i will delete it.